# How can I change the layout using QT

Tags: android, qt

I am developing an app for android using QT. After trying different ways, the layout of my app is not worked as expected. I want the graphicview layout to be placed on the top and the buttons placed at the bottom. Now the outcome of layout is just opposite.

**The design layout:**
[image]

**The outcome**:
[image]

**Code:**

```
ShowPic::ShowPic(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::ShowPic)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ui->horizontalLayout->addWidget(ui->pushButton);
    ui->horizontalLayout->addWidget(ui->pushButton_3);
    ui->horizontalLayout->addWidget(ui->pushButton_2);
    ui->verticalLayout_2->addWidget(ui->graphicsView);
    ui->verticalLayout_2->addLayout(ui->horizontalLayout);
    this->setLayout(ui->verticalLayout_2);
}
```

Comment: remove code and use only designer?

Comment: I want they occupy full of screen, how to do that?

Comment: In designer click on "ShowPic" widget, in top toolbar click on button "Layout in a Grid"

Comment: Thank you. It works now! :)